# Sound and Image files coming up null

Tags: java, image, audio

I am writing a game for a class and having trouble adding sound and images. We were given the framework from Andrew Davison's Killer Game Programming book to work with, and I feel like I am copying it exactly, but I get null whenever I try to play a sound or display the image.

The file name is reading correctly, but it's not finding the sound. I have the mp3 in the file.  I thought maybe the directory was wrong, so I keep changing it between /Sounds and /src/Sounds but it doesn't help. I'm completely stuck.

edit: after all that crap I just posted it was a simple problem of passing in the imsLoader before instantiating it. Sigh. I'll check to see if the soundLoader is the same issue. Thanks guys.

edit 2: the sound issue is not the same.I am getting a null result when creating a new input file stream for my sound file.

This is the SDL method after making changes to a URL.

```
   try {
        java.net.URL inFile = this.getClass().getResource("/Sounds/SDLInfo.txt");
        System.out.println("url " + inFile);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(inFile.openStream());
      if(in == null){
          System.out.println("in is null wtf");
          System.out.println("sndsFNm " + sndsFNm);
          System.out.println("in contents " + this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(sndsFNm));
      }
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
      StringTokenizer tokens;
      String line, name, fnm;
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.length() == 0)  // blank line
          continue;
        if (line.startsWith("//"))   // comment
          continue;

        tokens = new StringTokenizer(line);
        if (tokens.countTokens() != 2)
          System.out.println("Wrong no. of arguments for " + line);
        else {
          name = tokens.nextToken();
          fnm = tokens.nextToken();
          load(name, fnm);
        }
      }
      br.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { System.out.println("Error reading file: " + sndsFNm);
      System.exit(1);
    }
```

I instantiate the SDL loader before calling this method in my main class as follows:

```
    private static final String SDL_FILE = "SDLInfo.txt";
    private SDLLoader sdlLoader;
//initialize loaders and start music
sdlLoader = new SDLLoader(SDL_FILE); 
sdlLoader.play("bgmusic", true);
```

stack trace

```
url file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/MyName/Desktop/java%20programs/Zombie%20City/bin/Sounds/SDLInfo.txt
Problem with Sounds/peaceful_music.mp3
-- bgmusic/peaceful_music.mp3
Reading file: Sounds/clipsInfo.txt
url file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/MyName/Desktop/java%20programs/Zombie%20City/bin/Sounds/SDLInfo.txt
Problem with Sounds/peaceful_music.mp3
-- bgmusic/peaceful_music.mp3
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure what other code is needed"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Then I might have some vague idea of what `imsLoader` is and what the `getImage(String)` method does and how it does it.  BTW - I'd give a 95% probability that the problem lies in trying to access embedded resources as if they were loose resources on the file system (use `File` to access them) a opposed to loading them by `URL`.

Comment: I've changed the question as your help let me solve the image issue, I believe. I think I have included everything needed to troubleshoot the sound issue.

Comment: *"I think I have included everything needed"*  I see no SSCCE.  Did you read the linked document or just guess what it meant?

Comment: I read it, and it seemed to say only include relevant code to the issue. If you'd like to be able to compile and run I'll have to include quite a bit. I can do that if needed.

Comment: OK.. the code snippets are not an SSCCE, but they **do** confirm my initial suspicion was wrong.  The code **is** trying to access them as an embedded resource, but by getting an `InputStream` as opposed to an `URL`.  As an experiment, see if you can form an URL using `this.getClass().getResource("/Sounds/SDLInfo.txt"); // Note leading '/' - v. important.`

Comment: I was able to implement that code and am no longer getting an exception. My game will now play, but the music isn't actually playing. I'll add my changes to the question.

Comment: I'm about to sign off for a while.  If your new question is not solved soon after it is posted, let me know here, and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying for an input stream, form an URL using

```
this.getClass().getResource("/Sounds/SDLInfo.txt"); // Note leading '/' - v. important.
```

The reason I recommend this change is that I *know* that the `getResource(..)` method will interpret the leading `/` to mean *"search from the root of the class-path, as opposed to the package of the class".*

I never pinned down exactly how `getResourceAsStream(..)` treats the leading `/`, but it seemed ..different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a NullPointerException, it's probably from this line

`image = imsLoader.getImage(imageName);`

Perhaps `imsLoader` is null?

Comment: *"Perhaps.."* ..this should be a comment, instead of an answer?